# Why using unset() function cast the array to object?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

Here is my code:

```
return ApiResponse::Json(200, '', ['categories' => $categories], 200);
```

And here is a screenshot of the result:

[image: output 1]

Now, I need to unset items inside `categories` collection based on a specific logic. So I wrote this loop:

```
foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {
    if ($category->BusinessSubCategory->isEmpty())
          unset($categories[0]);
}

return ApiResponse::Json(200, '', ['categories' => $categories], 200);
```

And here is my new result: (which is casted to an object)

[image: output 2]

Well .. What's wrong? How can I keep the old structure after unseting some items?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `unset($categories[$key]);`?

Comment: @AndreaOlivato Doesn't matter .. it's just a sample ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {
    if ($category->BusinessSubCategory->isEmpty())
          unset($categories[$key]);

}

$categories = array_slice($categories->toArray(), 0, count($categories));

return ApiResponse::Json(200, '', ['categories' => $categories], 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `unset()` method doesn't change your type.

Your 'array' is not an array but a collection.

Try:

```
foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {
    if ($category->BusinessSubCategory->isEmpty()) {
        unset($categories[0]);
        break;
    }
}
$categories = array_values($categories->toArray());

return ApiResponse::Json(200, '', ['categories' => $categories], 200);
```

Notice if you're unseting the same element you should break loop after do that.

Comment: array_values(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection given"

Comment: So your type isn't even an array.

Comment: Well, I do know .. it's a collection before going inside the loop, and an object will be ouptuted after the loop

Comment: I changed post, try it this solution.

Comment: It would be written this way: `array_values($categories->toArray());`, since it's not static

Comment: Worked, thanks, could you please explain what was the issue?

Comment: Also, if you give me a upvote, I will be able to give you an upvote too (currently I have no reputation enough to be able give votes) .. Thanks in advance

Comment: After your deleted one key the array wasn't a list and that was a problemem for ApiResponse::Json() i think.

Comment: In 8.1 PHP, a method will be added that will allow you to check if the array keys start with 0 and are consecutive integers - https://php.watch/versions/8.1/array_is_list

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are using relationship so you can do without loop

```
$category=Category::with('BusinessSubCategory')
                     ->has('BusinessSubCategory')
                     ->get();
```

or using collection

```
$result= $categories->filter(function ($category){
    
           return  $category->BusinessSubCategory->isNotEmpty();
        });

dd($result->values()->toArray());
```

if `$categories` is not collection then use `collect($categories)->filter...`